# Solving an Integral Equation

Tags: integral-equations

Here is the Question;

Solve the integral equation,

$$\int_0^tY(u)Y(t-u)du = \frac12 (\sin t-t\cos t)$$

Really not sure how to go about this, took the Laplace transform of the right side getting,

$$\frac12\left(\frac{1}{s^2+1}-\frac{s^2-1}{(s^2+1)^2}\right)$$

Any suggestions to go about this would be great, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, for the left hand side you need the fact, the Laplace of the convolution equals the product of the Laplace, that is

> $$ \mathcal{L} (f*f) = \mathcal{L}(f) \mathcal{L}(f)= F(s)^2,$$

where $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f$  and it is given by

> $$ F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-sx}dx . $$

**Note:**

> $$\int_0^tY(u)Y(t-u)du = (Y*Y)(t). $$

Comment: Making sure I understand, so I will have the convolution of (Y*Y) equal to my right hand side. So I am thinking I could then solve for Y and take it's inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: @slow_Math: Yes, you are exactly right.